# Semicolon in password in azure function application setting connection string value

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, sqlconnection, azure-application-settings

Bonjour

Ive created a azure function which does not work in the Azure Portal.

The problem is that the password of the connnection string value contains a semicolon.

It works great locally when using '{Password}' in local.settings. This does not work when i enter this in the connection string value in the Application Settings of the function, I get the error Login failed for user '{User}'.

Without using ' ' it breaks the connection string value at the wrong place.

How do I use a password with semicolon in the Connection String value in Application Settings for Azure Function?

The connection string is built like this:
[ConnectionStringValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUhy4.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I put the connection string value into visual studio it added some characters to read it.

I copied that string which consequently is not the right one.

Solved by taking the original string with '{Password}'..

Thank you.